# Is there a MySQL command to convert a string to lowercase?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database of keywords that are presently mixed-case. However, I want to convert them all to lowercase. Is there an easy command to do this, either using MySQL or MySQL and PHP?

Comment: I guess you're also  using a dump from a friend who thought it would be a good idea to store usernames with capitalized letters.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET colname=LOWER(colname);
```

Comment: if the collation of a column is set to `ascii_bin`, wont this automatically convert everything to lowercase or am i mistaken?

Answer (score 29):

Yes, the function is LOWER() or LCASE() (they both do the same thing).

For example:

```
select LOWER(keyword) from my_table
```

Answer (score 12):

`SELECT LOWER(foo) AS foo FROM bar`

Answer (score 9):

You can use the functions LOWER() or LCASE().

These can be used both on columns or string literals.  e.g.

```
SELECT LOWER(column_name) FROM table a;
```

or

```
SELECT column_name FROM table a where column = LOWER('STRING')
```

LCASE() can be substituted for LOWER() in both examples.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `colnameone`=LOWER(`colnameone`);
```

or

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `colnameone`=LCASE(`colnameone`);
```

Both functions will work the same.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try looking it up? Google, manual...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lower

```
mysql> SELECT LOWER('QUADRATICALLY');
        -> 'quadratically'
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting to note that the field name is renamed and if you reference it in a function, you will not get its value unless you give him an alias (that can be its own name)

Example: I use a function to dynamically get a field name value:

```
function ColBuilder ($field_name) {
…
While ($result = DB_fetch_array($PricesResult)) {
$result[$field_name]
}
…
}
```

my query being:
    SELECT LOWER(itemID), … etc..

needed to be changed to:
    SELECT LOWER(itemID) **as itemID**, … etc..

Comment: This does not sound like an answer, or?

Comment: it completes the answer, warning that using LOWER() in specific situations may not provide the expected result without additional aliasing.

Answer (score -3):

use `LOWER` function to convert data or string in lower case.

```
select LOWER(username) from users;
```

or

```
select * from users where LOWER(username) = 'vrishbh';
```

Comment: What does this add that wasn't in the *five year old* answers?

Answer (score -6):

I believe in php you can use

```
strtolower()
```

so you could make a php to read all the entries in the table then use that command to print them back as lower case

Comment: The OP requested MySQL or MySQL/PHP.