# MYSQL Change uppercase to title case

Tags: mysql

I have some blog titles that are in uppercase and id like to change them to title case? Is there a way to do this using SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Ok Thanks is there a way to find the uppercase titles using SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to convert MySQL data into Title Case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191605/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-mysql-data-into-title-case)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I misread ... MySQL....

No,

[Is there a simple way to convert MySQL data into Title Case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191605/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-mysql-data-into-title-case)