# Correct Syntax for MariaDB Update Statement

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am in the process of updating some old Access/SQL queries to run in a MariaDB environment. The following `update` statement is causing me problems. I've been working through it, but still haven't resolved it. I did try replacing `Nz` with `COALESCE()`. I also made note that `StrComp` is now `STRCMP` in MariaDB. It seems that `STRCONV` doesn't exist in MariaDB.

My question is: what does the following code do, and how can I reproduce this in a MariaDB-friendly way?

```
UPDATE ft.contacts
SET firstname = StrConv(firstname,3)
WHERE (((firstname)>"") 
AND ((StrComp(UCase(Nz(firstname)),Nz(firstname),0))=0)) 
OR (((firstname)>"") 
AND ((StrComp(LCase(Nz(firstname)),Nz(firstname),0))=0));
```

Comment: As far as I know, MariaDB does not have a "proper case" function, so you cannot directly convert this code.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: you could write a function that does the 'proper case' conversion, examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181937/how-to-do-a-proper-case-formatting-of-a-mysql-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for mimic the Capitalize function you could use

```
CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(firstname, 1)), SUBSTRING(firstname, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks, this with a WHERE clause to check for `""` works in my case.