# Mysql String Functions of Proper Case

Tags: mysql, string

How convert "john santos lumbao eduardo" INTO a proper case like "John Santos Lumbao Eduardo".?

Comment: Since I have many records with different number of words...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191605/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-mysql-data-into-title-case

Comment: I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191605/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-mysql-data-into-title-case

Answer (score 2):

You would think that the world’s most popular open source database, as MySQL like to call itself, would have a function for making items title case (where the first letter of every word is capitalized). Sadly it doesn’t.

This is the best solution i found Just create a stored procedure / function that will do the trick

```
mysql> 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proper;
SET GLOBAL  log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION proper( str VARCHAR(128) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
BEGIN
DECLARE c CHAR(1);
DECLARE s VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE bool INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT ' ()[]{},.-_!@;:?/';
SET s = LCASE( str );
WHILE i <= LENGTH( str ) DO   
    BEGIN
SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );
IF LOCATE( c, punct ) > 0 THEN
SET bool = 1;
ELSEIF bool=1 THEN
BEGIN
IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN
BEGIN
SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));
SET bool = 0;
END;
ELSEIF c >= '0' AND c <= '9' THEN
SET bool = 0;
END IF;
END;
END IF;
SET i = i+1;
END;
END WHILE;
RETURN s;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

then

```
update table set col = proper(col)
```

or

```
select proper( col ) as properCOl 
from table
```

In your case

```
proper ( "John Santos Lumbao Eduardo" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar in SQL server not in MYSQL. But it may help you

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CamelCase]
(@Str varchar(8000))
RETURNS varchar(8000) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result varchar(2000)
  SET @Str = LOWER(@Str) + ' '
  SET @Result = ''
  WHILE 1=1
  BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('% %',@Str) = 0 BREAK
    SET @Result = @Result + UPPER(Left(@Str,1))+
    SubString  (@Str,2,CharIndex(' ',@Str)-1)
    SET @Str = SubString(@Str,
      CharIndex(' ',@Str)+1,Len(@Str))
  END
  SET @Result = Left(@Result,Len(@Result))
  RETURN @Result
END
---------------------------------------------------
-- HOW TO USE --
-- SELECT dbo.CamelCase('hARi nARAyan shARMa')
-- Output: Hari Narayan Sharma
---------------------------------------------------
GO
```