# Delete common prefix of all tables in DB in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

All my tables have the prefix `bn_`. For example, a table would be named `bn_blast`.

Any SQL command to run that will delete all the prefixes from all the tables?

Comment: What with stored procedures/functions/foreign key constraints that depends on that tables?

Comment: What? Sorry, I don't know this field enough to understand you well...

Comment: I guess you have table like `bn_customer` and you want to rename it to `customer`. It is not so simply since many other database object can depend on it

Comment: Hello, indeed that's what I need... No way to do so for all at once? For all tables (and the objects in them) at once? Ben,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a one-liner.

In the console:

> mysql -u root -p -AN -e" select concat('RENAME TABLE ', concat(table_name, concat(' TO ', concat(substr(table_name,4 ), ';')))) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='db_name' " > renaming.sql

Enter password when prompted.

Open the "renaming.sql" file, in the first line, add "use db_name;" and then save.
Then, do the following:

> mysql -u root -p < renaming.sql

Enter password when prompted.

Now, check your tables:

> show tables;

Output: Before

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_STACK     |
+---------------------+
| db_answer           |
| db_answers          |
| db_circle           |
| db_fee              |
| db_housing          |
| db_im_originals     |
| db_im_savegroups    |
| db_im_savespecs     |
| db_location_share   |
| db_order1           |
| db_orderitems       |
| db_patientinfo      |
| db_quest            |
| db_share            |
| db_t2               |
| db_tbdatabaseerrors |
| db_tblchanges       |
| db_test             |
| db_test1            |
| db_test_fid         |
| db_test_table       |
| db_testing          |
| db_user             |
+---------------------+
```

Output: After

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_STACK   |
+-------------------+
| answer            |
| answers           |
| circle            |
| fee               |
| housing           |
| im_originals      |
| im_savegroups     |
| im_savespecs      |
| location_share    |
| order1            |
| orderitems        |
| patientinfo       |
| quest             |
| share             |
| t2                |
| tbdatabaseerrors  |
| tblchanges        |
| test              |
| test1             |
| test_fid          |
| test_table        |
| testing           |
| user              |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: This was excellent, and combined with the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889163/4844269 you can also uppercase the first character of each table name if you like. Thus:
`
mysql -u root -p -AN -e" select concat('RENAME TABLE ', concat(table_name, concat(' TO ', concat(concat(upper(substr(table_name,5, 1 )), lower(substr(table_name from 6))), ';')))) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='SCHEMA' " > SCHEMArenaming.sql
`

Answer (score 1):

[image: screenshot for steps 1 to 4]

To remove a common prefix for all tables in a MySQL database using phpMyAdmin:

1. Select the database.
2. Go to the "**Structure**" tab.
3. Scroll to the bottom, and click the "**Check All**" checkbox. This selects all tables.
4. In the "**With selected:**" dropdown next to it, select "**Replace table prefix**". This takes you to the "Replace table prefix" page.
5. In the "**From**" field, type in the prefix that you want to remove, such as `shop_`.
6. In the "**To**" field, leave it empty.
7. Click "**Submit**"... and boom! Done!

You can add or rename prefixes in a similar way.

---

Tip: if your database has lots of other tables and you want to select only the tables containing a certain string, you can make use of the debug JavaScript console. For example, to select all tables containing `shop_`, run this:

```
$('form[name=tablesForm]').find('th:contains(shop_)').closest('tr').children(':first-child')
    .find(':input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true)
```