# FUNCTION tcase does not exist

Tags: php, mysql

FUNCTION `db_name.tcase` does not exist.
I am using mysql select query i.e

```
select tcase(column_name) from table
```

which is giving error on localhost saying `tcase` does not exist.
php version 5.6
mysql version 4.8
its working proper on live website but not on localhost

Comment: did you match versions from both ?

Comment: There is no function like `tcase`. Someone created it as custom function and you have used it as it is without defining.

Comment: try to upgrade a db version on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function like `tcase`. Someone created it as custom function and you have used it as it is without defining.

Look here [Is there a simple way to convert MySQL data into Title Case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191605/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-mysql-data-into-title-case), how `tcase` function is defined.

Comment: thnks for your ans