# Update ALL CAPS values to Capitalize

Tags: mysql

> Is it possible to select values in all caps and update those values to
>   capitalize with the same query?

I am able to select them like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE name REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z]+$';
```

Comment: Can you explain the distinction between "all caps" and "to capitalize"?  Do you mean "uppercase" to "titlecase"?

Comment: Do you want "VERY IMPORTANT" to be "Very Important" or "Very important"?

Comment: Also, why are you using `binary` on a string?

Comment: Yes, CAPS to Caps. Sorry, using CSS lingo 'capitalize'.

Comment: adding BINARY allows me to select all caps entries.

Comment: @santa Oh lord, MySQL implicit case-insensitivity strikes again.

Comment: @Schwern ...not really much of a MySQL... not sure what it means.

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1
set name = ...
where name = regexp binary '^[A-Z]+$';
```

Where that `...` is any number of [solutions from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191605/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-mysql-data-into-title-case).

Do this in a transaction in case there's a mistake.